# store objects in $_GET

Tags: php

how can i store an object in the $_GET array in PHP. i want to pass an object containing database information from one page to another page via the $_GET array, so there would be no need to access the database again.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to do that? Constantly serializing and unserializing data might be more resource-intensive than a simple db query. Also, I would look into something like memcached.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "an object containing database information"? This could mean a whole result set (maybe plus metadata) wrapped in some object or simply one or two values/columns from one single record (which would change the story quite a bit).

Comment: @VolkerK does it matter?

Answer (score 5):

To pass any sort of object, you'd have to **[`serialize`](http://www.php.net/serialize)** it on one end, and **[`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/unserialize)** it on the other end.

But note that **this will not work for database connections themselves** : the connection to the database is automatically closed when a PHP script ends.

You could pass some connection informations, like login, host, or stuff like that *(but that would not be a good idea -- quite not safe to expose such critical informations !)* ; but you cannot pass a connection resource.

Comment: Not a good idea to pass database login info around in $_GET for security reasons.

Comment: Be careful with such recoomendations. Someone could take it too literally and start passing database login and pass over query string :)

Comment: That's why I didn't talk about password ^^ but I'll edit my answer to make it more clear that this is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

You would need to serialize it to text (possibly using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)), then generate a URL that included it in the query string (making sure that it was [urlencoded](http://www.php.net/urlencode))

Answer (score 1):

Really, you should be passing data from one page to another via the $_SESSION variable instead, if possible. That is what sessions are for. Ideally just store an id in the session and look up the data on each page. If you do use $_SESSION then it is as simple as ...

```
$_SESSION['myarray'] = $myarrayobject;
$_SESSION['someotherthing'] = 42;
```

If you have to use $_GET, then I would recommend just passing an id of some kind, then re-looking up the data on each page refesh.

Keep in mind, it would be easy for a malicious user to change the values that are sent via $_GET between pages, so make sure there is nothing that can be abused in this information.

Comment: No, sessions are not for passing database information from one page to another. Database is already on it.

Comment: I agree. but they are for passing information between pages. The OP wants to pass database infomation around via the $_GET var. If he must pass this data around, it would be better done in the $_SESSION var. As I point out though, passing an id of some kind and re-looking up the data would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

That's very bad idea.
Database were invented to serve each request, while query string were designed to pass only commands and identificators, not tons of data between browser and server

Comment: You seem to be confusing comments and answers.

Comment: @David it **is** answer. the only one possible for such a question.

Comment: it should be a comment, since it doesn't really answer the question. I might have upvoted it as a comment.

Comment: Stop being robots guys. Try to think before answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using get, another possibility to pass something from one page to another is to use the $_SESSION array and then to unset that variable on the other side whenever you're done with it.  I've found that to be a pretty good way to do this.

Like everyone else has said though, passing database information can be a bad idea, assuming the information you're passing isn't something like username, first name, etc.  If that's what you're passing when you say "database information" then I would store all that stuff in the $_SESSION variable and then destroy their session when they log out.  Don't store the entire connection or something.

Comment: Bad reason to use sessions. The OP want just to help his database. So, he doesn't need any solution at all. As has database doesn't need any help.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said before you should avoid (mis-)using GET parameters as a "cache" for overly complex and loooong data.
On the other hand your question is vague enough to assume that you want to transmit only a few values. And your "second" script needs nothing else from the database, in fact it *might* not even have to check if those values came from a database at all.
In this case extract the values from your database result and append them as parameters to the url. Try to make the parameter list as simple as possible but yet unambiguous. [http_build_query()](http://docs.php.net/http_build_query) can help you with that.
But keep in mind that you want to keep GET operations idempotent as described in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html.

```
if ( isset($_GET['a'], $_GET['b'], $_GET['c']) ) {
  // this doesn't care about the values in the database at all.
  echo 'product: ', $_GET['a'] * $_GET['b'] * $_GET['c'], "\n";
}
else {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'localonly', 'localonly'); 
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  // let's make it a self-contained example (and extra constly) by creating a temproary table ...
  $pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (id int auto_increment, a int, b int, c int, primary key(id))');
  // ... with some garbage data
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO foo (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?)');
  for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $stmt->execute(array(rand(1,10), rand(1,10), rand(1,10)));
  }

  foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT a,b,c FROM foo', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    printf('<a href="?%s">%s</a><br />',
      http_build_query($row),
      join(' * ', $row)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Everyone seems to assume the worst (tons of data, complex serialization, emulating persistence, ...all the wrong reasons). So I thought "Why not assume the 'best', simplest thing, only in a maybe weird wording of the question?" ;-) But seriously there are many things in between those two extremes where I would consider using GET parameters as a viable alternative to another db query. And hey, at least I put the word 'idempotent ' and http\_build\_query() into the answer, which is a nice function to simplify building query strings, isn't it? ;-)